# Code don't work, can't read property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, classname, typeerror

What is wrong with this code?

```
var divarray = [];
var articleHTML = [];
var absHTML;
var keyHTML;
var bodyHTML = [];
var i = 0;
divarray = document.getElementById("yui-main").getElementsByTagName("div");
for ( var j in divarray) {
    if(divarray[i].className == "articleBody"){
        articleHTML = divarray[i];
        for( var k in articleHTML ){
            bodyHTML[i] = '';
            if(articleHTML[i].className == "issueMiniFeature"){continue;}
            if(articleHTML[i].className == "abstract"){absHTML = articleHTML[i]; continue;}
            if(articleHTML[i].className == "journalKeywords"){keyHTML = articleHTML[i]; continue;}
            bodyHTML[i] = articleHTML[i];
        }
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
```

I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: You should be using `divarray[j]` instead of `divarray[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a very strange loop.

```
 for (var j in array) {
    // use array[i]
    ++ i
 }
```

The problem is `.getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an array, but an array-like interface. For example:

```
>>> for (var j in document.getElementsByTagName('body')) console.log(j)
0
length
item
namedItem
```

Therefore, in your `for`/`in` loop, `i` will go up to `array.length + 2` instead of `array.length - 1`. Since `array[array.length + 2]` does not exist, it will return `undefined` and throw the error when you try to access a property of it.

---

Just always use

```
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++ i) {
  ...
}
```

with arrays.

Comment: I deleted my original answer once I noticed how bizarre the code was.

Comment: I meant that to be a foreach. My, I am all mixed up today!

Comment: I later found out that I had the right idea, but was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize `articleHTML` as an array, then you're apparently setting `articleHTML` to an HTMLElement (`divarray[i]`) but then treating it like an array (`articleHTML[i]`) — this actually tries to get the `i` property of the HTMLElement that you pulled out of `divarray`, which doesn't exist, and then you try to get the `className` of this undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
var divarray = [];
var articleHTML = [];
var absHTML;
var keyHTML;
var bodyHTML = [];
var i = 0;
divarray = document.getElementById("yui-main").getElementsByTagName("div");
for ( var j in divarray) {
    if(divarray[j].className == "articleBody"){
        alert("found");
        articleHTML = divarray[j];
        break;
    }
    bodyHTML[i] = '';
    if(divarray[j].className == "issueMiniFeature"){continue;}
    if(divarray[j].className == "abstract"){absHTML = divarray[j]; continue;}
    if(divarray[j].className == "journalKeywords"){keyHTML = divarray[j]; continue;}
    bodyHTML[i] = divarray[j];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: forget it, I will just open a new question with updated code.